# Optimal presentation of discrete double inequality

Tags: plotting

I have the double inequality
$$G(n) = \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{\omega(n)} \tau(n)^2 < 
F(n) \leq 
\left( \frac{3}{4} \right)^{\omega(n)} \tau(n)^2 = H(n),$$
where $F(n) = \sum_{d \mid n} \tau(d)$. (What $\omega$ and $\tau$ are can be inferred from the code below.)

The question I have (which might be not appropriate) is: what might be a good way to plot this double inequality? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

My best idea at present is to plot the two ratios $F(n)/G(n)$ and $H(n)/F(n)$ so that it can be seen from the plot that they both stay above $1$. The code I am using:

```
F[n_] := DivisorSum[n, DivisorSigma[0, #] &] 

DiscretePlot[{(3/4)^(PrimeNu[n])*(DivisorSigma[0, n])^2/F[n], 
F[n]/((1/2)^(PrimeNu[n])*(DivisorSigma[0, n])^2)}, {n, 2, 400}, 
PlotLabels -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Building off of that, I think it's nice to put $F(n)$ in the denominator each time, and shift the origin of the axes to `{0,1}`. Then the one bigger than $F(n)$ is above the axis, and the one smaller than $F(n)$ is below it: `DiscretePlot[{(3/4)^(PrimeNu[n])*(DivisorSigma[0, n])^2/F[n], ((1/2)^(PrimeNu[n])*(DivisorSigma[0, n])^2)/F[n]}, {n, 2,400}, PlotLabels -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 1}]`

Comment: Another similar way is to not shift the axes origin, and use `-` instead of `/`, but then you'd also want a `PlotRange -> Full`, and the graph of that is a bit wilder, but they're more similar to each other. You also probably want to get rid of the x axis markers in this case. `DiscretePlot[{(3/4)^(PrimeNu[n])*(DivisorSigma[0, n])^2 - F[n], ((1/2)^(PrimeNu[n])*(DivisorSigma[0, n])^2) - F[n]}, {n, 2, 400}, PlotLabels -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Full, Ticks -> {False, Automatic}]`

Comment: I haven't yet tried the second suggestion, but the first one already makes the plot much better.

Comment: Feel free to post an answer by the way.

Comment: Ok, posted these comments as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variation on thorimur's second method: We can use custom ticks for the vertical axis and put a gap between the two curves to have the horizontal axis visible:

```
ClearAll[g, h, F]
g[n_] := (1/2)^PrimeNu[n] DivisorSigma[0, n]^2
h[n_] := (3/4)^PrimeNu[n]*DivisorSigma[0, n]^2
F[n_] := DivisorSum[n, DivisorSigma[0, #] &]

gap = 20;
vticks = Join[Charting`FindTicks[{-100 - gap/2, -gap/2}, {100, 0}][-100-gap/2, -gap/2],
   Charting`FindTicks[{gap/2, 100 + gap/2}, {0, 100}][gap, 100 + gap/2]];

DiscretePlot[{gap/2 + h[n] - F[n], g[n] - F[n] - gap/2}, {n, 2, 400},
 Filling -> {1 -> gap/2, 2 -> -gap/2}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, vticks}, 
 PlotLegends -> {HoldForm[F[n] - g[n]], HoldForm[h[n] - F[n]]},
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {-100, 100}, 
 GridLines -> {None, {-gap/2, gap/2}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Building off of what you have, I think it's nice to put $F(n)$ in the denominator each time, and shift the origin of the axes to `{0,1}`. Then the one bigger than $F(n)$ is above the axis, and the one smaller than $F(n)$ is below it:

```
DiscretePlot[{(3/4)^(PrimeNu[n])*(DivisorSigma[0, n])^2/F[n],
  ((1/2)^(PrimeNu[n])*(DivisorSigma[0, n])^2)/F[n]}, {n, 2,400},
  PlotLabels -> Automatic, AxesOrigin -> {0, 1}]
```

[image: A plot generated by the above code.]

Another similar way is to use `-` instead of `/`, and keep the axis where it is originally. In this case you'd also want `PlotRange -> Full`; the graph of this is a bit wilder, but not as lopsided from top to bottom. You'd also probably want to get rid of the x-axis markers in this case, as they overlap with the curves:

```
DiscretePlot[{(3/4)^(PrimeNu[n])*(DivisorSigma[0, n])^2 - F[n],
  ((1/2)^(PrimeNu[n])*(DivisorSigma[0, n])^2) - F[n]}, {n, 2, 400},
  PlotLabels -> Automatic, PlotRange -> Full, Ticks -> {False, Automatic}]
```

[image: A plot generated by the above code.]

Comment: I'll wait a little before accepting in case anyone else feels like contributing something different.

Comment: yeah, no problem! I sort of expected someone would come in with something much better, which was why I put it in a comment in the first place.